# How to access individual theme settings from code?

Tags: 8

I was building a block for which I have to provide bubblable metadata. The data in this block is depending on individual theme configurations as well as the global theme settings.

So I tried the following:

```
$config = \Drupal::config('system.theme.global');
$bubbleable_metadata->addCacheableDependency($config);

$config2 = \Drupal::config('bartik.settings');
$bubbleable_metadata->addCacheableDependency($config2);
```

This however obviously does not work if the theme is not set to bartik. I have been attempting to find the theme configuration in `\Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()`, but that does not provide this data.

I suppose I could try `$config = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName() . '.settings';`, but I'd like to learn if there are better ways.

How to get the configuration (or config name) of the current active theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is actually the recommended way. It is used in [`theme_get_settings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_setting/8.3.x) as well:

```
$theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();
...
  if ($theme_settings = \Drupal::config($theme . '.settings')->get()) {
    ...
  }
```